# Server side request cannot use redirect_uri from iOS client for facebook OAuth

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am very new to development so please forgive the occasional misused term, general lack of knowledge, and the poorly worded title.

I am building a new login flow for my company following the guidelines outlined for 'manually building a login flow' at developer.faceboook.com.

After making a request to this URL from the user's device:

GET

https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?

response_type=code

&redirect_uri={app-id}://authorize

&client_id={my-app-client-id}

I receive a 'code' which I can in turn use for authentication. The redirect uri above allows me to open the app after the user has granted permission through application(:handleOpen:).

I send the code to our backend and attempt to make this request:

GET

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token?

client_id={app-id}

&redirect_uri={app-id}://authorize

&client_secret={app-secret}

&code={code-parameter} <- received from initial request

The guidelines say that the redirect_uri should match that of the uri from the first request, which mine does, but I still receive this response:

{

"error": {

```
"message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",

"type": "OAuthException",

"code": 100,

"fbtrace_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
```

}

}

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is allowed by Facebook. Since the requests are originating from two different sources and the uri provided in the second request doesn't really do anything if the request is made from the backend. I should also mention I am testing the second response using Postman. Is what I'm doing possible or do I have to rethink the flow? Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that needs to be an HTTP(S) URL ... Why do you want to use this flow in the first place? For native mobile apps, you should use the SDKs Facebook provides, and handle login via those.

Comment: We are using this flow because we want to use fb for authentication and validation but create our own account for the user using the information we get from facebook. We considered using the SDK but we realized that it isn't as secure if we gather the info on the phone and then try to send it to our backend

Comment: _"but we realized that it isn't as secure if we gather the info on the phone and then try to send it to our backend"_ - interesting perspective ... "interesting" here meaning that goes against what most people would probably argue. Anyway, this login flow is expected to be used in an HTTP(S) context - don't expect it to work with other (pseudo-) protocols, especially ones specific to devices that Facebook encourages you to use their own SDKs on ...

Comment: I was just passing on what our head dev said about the lack of security. As I mentioned I'm new to development and am curious, what would most people argue? Do you mind elaborating, or maybe pointing me toward some resource that explains what you mean?

Comment: Login on the client, send the access token to the server, and then make API calls from there. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#tokenhijacking